# Is it necessary to cache data returned from CoreData?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I store data in an iPhone app using CoreData.  The data stored is intended to represent a tree, with each record being a node (with pointer to its parent).  As the user navigates through this tree, I cache the current parent and current set of children in an NSArray.  I initially thought this made sense because it could allow quicker access of sibling nodes (useful when the data is presented in a UITableView and the user scrolls).  I felt that using CoreData to perform a "get all children" query each time  the next child is required would be inefficient (i.e. I'd be making the same query n times for n children, and just returning the ith result each time).

Now, I am not so sure this is necessary nor smart (mostly because I've learned that CoreData is a beast I have yet to fully understand).
Does anybody know whether this is good practice?  I know CoreData does a lot for free including the caching of results, but since I know my data is going to be used like a tree, would my implementation (or some other outside-of-CoreData cache implementation) be more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you use coredata and an UITableView you should use a [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFetchedResultsController). It does all the caching for you, and for sure it does it better than you.
the fetchedResultsController also takes care of deletion, changing and insertion of coredata objects, ie it tells you when to update the tableview. but for the latter to function you have to set up the fetchedresultscontroller delegate methods. there is a complete example of the delegate functions included in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

in general, get rid of your caching, it's not needed.